# how to fetch given range of datarows from database using .skip(i).take(j) using lambda expressions navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda

I am using the following code to fetch data to bind a gridview, but for performance issues i only want to get selected range of datarows say 1-10 for firstpage 11-20 for second page ....   How can i do that modifying  following code

```
 public IQueryable<Employee> SelectEmployees(string SortColumn, string SortOrder, long UserID,---int start,---int end)
    {
            IUnitOfWork objUow;
            var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "Employee");
            var sortProperty = Expression.Property(arg, SortColumn);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(sortProperty, arg);
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IQueryable<Employee>));
            var orderByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), SortOrder, new Type[] { typeof(Employee), sortProperty.Type }, new Expression[] { param, lambda });
            var orderLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<Employee>, IQueryable<Employee>>>(orderByCall, param).Compile();
            var Ids = objUow.Repository<Users>().Entities.Where((x => x.ID == UserID)).Select(y => y.Id);
            return orderLambda(objUow.Repository<Employee>().Entities.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.Status == 1 && Ids.Contains(x.CheckID)));
   }
```

I have Tried skip().take() but it resuts in error . ...

```
 return orderLambda((objUow.Repository<Employee>().Entities.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.Status == 1 && Ids.Contains(x.CheckID))).Skip(0).Take(10));
```

An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

can i do something like below

```
 IQueryable<Employee> Obj= orderLambda(objUow.Repository<Employee>().Entities.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.InvalidStatus == 1 && shopids.Contains(x.CheckID)));
           Obj.Skip(0).Take(10);
```

Comment: Show the skip/take code *and* the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
 return orderLambda((objUow.Repository<Employee>()
  .Entities.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true && x.Status == 1 && Ids.Contains(x.CheckID)))
  .OrderBy(x=> x.CheckID) // you must order the results before skip and take
  .Skip(0)
  .Take(10));
```

The error is telling you that

**Edit**

To order by a string, you may need the [System.Linq.Dynamic nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) package, and namespace. Then you can replace my OrderBy with OrderBy(SortOrder)
Then you can do

```
OrderBy(string.Format("{0} {1}", SortOrder, SortDirection)) // where Sort direction can be "descending" if it's reversed
// replace 0 & 10 as appropriate
```

Comment: but i have to order by the column and Order passed in parameter.. see the  code before the return statement  var orderLambda=..

Comment: That's fine. You just have to order by something. I picked one of the properties I saw, but it just must be ordered.

Comment: With order by clauses specified as string you need something like System.Linq.Dynamic referenced

Comment: @Thanks reckface for your time. by the way my code is perfectly working with sorting.. the only problem is it loads whole data according to the query. I 'll try your code.

Comment: If you call skip/take against the IQueriable DbSet, it doesn't load all the data into Query. Look at SQL profiler, or test it in LinqPad, you'll notice the SQL command is created to select top...

Comment: Hello.. whts your opinion about the performance if a get the full list in an object and filter that object to take desired number of rows?

Comment: Why would you want to? You can apply the filters to the IQueryable against the db context instead of pulling the entire list. The performance implications depends on the size of the list, but it's generally bad design. Did any of these answer you question? If so pick one as the answer.

Comment: No. the answers given are working ,i know. but doesnt fit with my code. ie the 6 line of code before the return. may be my inexperience

Answer (score 1):

you need to know how many records you want to skip every time you query the db.
in order to do that you should multiply page number to page size.
here is an example:

```
int skipAmount = pageNumber * pageSize;
_repository.Where(a => a.IsDeleted != false)
   .OrderBy(a => a.Date)
      .Skip(skipAmount)
         .Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: thats okay, but here i am Ordering using Expression .lambda so no need to  add orderby pls note the code above return..